# 'Meta file .dll could not be found' during PS Add-Type (C# code)

Tags: c#, powershell, add-type

I want to execute C# code in a PS script by using Add-Type. But I receive: 
`Metadata file 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.dll' could not be found`. The C# code uses a NuGet package called "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus".

My referenced assembly seems not to work. Here is my code:

PS

```
$cmd = {

$Assem = ( 
"Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus", 
"netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"
) 

$Source = (Get-Content -Path "D:\myPath\csharp-code.cs" -ReadCount 0) -join "`n"

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp 
[ABC.Azure.ServiceBus.TopicSubscriber]::test()
}

# Execute script as Job to avoid "Add-Type"-conflict during development changes
$j = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd

do 
{
  Receive-Job -Job $j
} while ( $j.State -eq "Running" )
```

C#

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace ABC.Azure.ServiceBus
{
  class TopicSubscriber
  {
    bool test()
    {
        <more code>
    }
  }
}
```

Whats the root of this issue and how can I fix it? Unfortunately I am not very familiar with PS nor C#.

Comment: Go to guess is that you have an architecture mismatch. Are you running x64 PowerShell trying to reference an x32 assembly or vice versa?

Comment: @Matt You are right. I checked with `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` and `file .\<path>\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.dll` and I am running a 64bit PS but the .dll is a 32bit portable executable (PE32).
But how can I change the PS project to 32bit or get the 64bit version of the .dll(if there exists one)? I am using VS2017.

Comment: I just found it.
To set PowerShell to 32/64bit go to: 
`Tools->Options->PowerShell Tools->Bitness->x86`
Though this still doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: What if you run x86 PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're receiving is essentially: `File not found.`

The root cause is your relative path of the referenced assembly in -

```
$assemblies = @(
    'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus'
    'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
)
```

since `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` isn't in the GAC.

I suspect if you use `Set-Location` where the `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.dll` file is, you will resolve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately `Set-Location` to the .dll folder or loading the .dll with `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(<filePath>)` didn't help.